# Javascript: Rows of string characters

Tags: javascript, html, string, charat

So I am trying to create a function that takes the first input as a number and the second input as a string. the function should then change the innerHTML of the div with the characters of the second input. For example. if the first input was number 2 and second input was hello the innerHTML should change to:

```
h
ee
```

if the first was number 5 all else being the same:

```
h
ee
lll
llll
ooooo
```

I know I must use str.charAT and possibly a for loop (probably any loop) but just cant seem to piece it together in my head. I have been stuck on this for 6 hours now and I have no idea how to do it. So here I am asking for help XD, help my please! If any hints are out there I would gladly take them, this is just a random exercise to help me get used to js. If you would rather like to give the entire that is fine too, I mean it helps alot more than a hint considering i can learn from it.

the number cannot go past the amount of characters within the string. So far here is the html and javascript that I made.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="q2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div> Input1<input id="input1" type="text"></div>
  <div> Input2<input id="input2" type="text"></div>
  <div> Result<div id="result"></div></div>
  <button onclick="compute()">Compute</button>
</body>
<html>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function compute(){
  var n = Number(document.getElementById("input1").value);
  var v = document.getElementById("input2").value;
  var answer = document.getElementById("result");
  var i,j;
answer.innerHTML = "";
if(n){

}else{
  alert("whatever is in input 1 is not a number ya fookin cheeky buggah");
}
if(n>v.length){
  alert("number 1 bigger than word 2");
}

for(i=0;i<n;i++){
for(j=0;)
}

}
```

Comment: Your code has syntax errors, looking at it, doesn't look like you've tried, is that a fair assessment?

Comment: @JaromandX Works fine for me? I didnt see any errors, unless you count my failed attempt on thinking of the loop code an error XD, i mean if you mean the appearence sucks then yea your probably right about that, idk how to make it look good or anything.

Comment: `for(j=0;)` is an error

Comment: @JaromandaX XD sorry if I wasn't clear enough, that is part of my failed attempt on making a loop that would work, i just stopped it right there because i knew that what i was doing wouldnt work, at most if i got it to work it would gave me rows of equal amounts characters the way I was thinking of it.

Comment: This looks like homework to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer using nested for loops and charAt

```
function compute() {
    var n = Number(document.getElementById("input1").value);
    var v = document.getElementById("input2").value;
    var answer = document.getElementById("result");
    var i, j, c, s = "";
    if (n) {
    } 
    else {
        alert("whatever is in input 1 is not a number ya fookin cheeky buggah");
    }
    if (n > v.length) {
        alert("number 1 bigger than word 2");
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        c = v.charAt(i);
        if (i > 0) {
            s += "<br />";
        }
        for (j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            s += c;
        }
    }
    answer.innerHTML = s;
}
```

Comment: Wow, that seems alot easier then i thought it would have had to been with loops. Thanks a huge ton!!!! :D

Comment: This made me understand a part of the for loop that was boggling my mind for a while (it was stupid how i didnt think this but...) once a function has fulfilled its purpose it is gone until it is called back again, but when its called back again, so is the first statement (i.e in this the first statement of the j for loop is j=0) so the variable j here basically resets to 0 everytime the loop is called. Thank you so much dude! I mean i may be stupid to not know a basic concept like that, but that just means i wouldn't have figured it out without this help!

Answer (score 4):

This does what you need, however it may be using some array functions you're not familiar with

```
function compute() {
    var n = Number(document.getElementById("input1").value);
    var v = document.getElementById("input2").value;
    var answer = document.getElementById("result");

    if (!n) {
        alert("whatever is in input 1 is not a number ya fookin cheeky buggah");
    }
    if (n > v.length) {
        alert("number 1 bigger than word 2");
    }
    answer.innerHTML = [].slice.call(v, 0, n).map(function(letter, index) {
        return new Array(index+2).join(letter);
    }).join('<br />');
}
```

1. `slice` - we only want the first n characters
2. `map` - for each character, run the callback function
3. the `callback` function creates an Empty array which is 2 larger than the current index (0 based index)
4. joins this array on the letter - which produces index + 1 letters
5. the mapped array is joined by `<br />`
6. the result of this is output to `answer.innerHTML`

the `answer.innerHTML` code in ES2015 (ES6) would be

```
   answer.innerHTML = [].slice.call(v, 0, n).map((letter, index) => letter.repeat(index+1)).join('<br />')
```

Comment: +1 for good answer, though it seems like the OP needs help with homework, so might be too complex for the current assignment :p

Comment: Split and slice has a nice alliterative ring to it! `[].reduce.call(v, ...)` works too.

Comment: I realise the answer may be above his weight class, but I consider this a more correct way than nester for loops and charAt

Comment: @Malk - I could've also ES2015'd the code :p - and your method would mean more logic in the callback :p

Comment: Should have done that, preach the new standard.  Hail ES2015!  p.s. I'm glad you aren't referring to it as ES6

Comment: Thank you for your answer! it works great, but hard to understand, new terms here and there that I have yet to learn, but google is always there for me :D, I will try my best to understand this by searching up the individual terms

Comment: @KingLynx - I can post an answer using for loops if you'd like to see one

Answer (score 0):

```
function compute() {
var n = Number(document.getElementById("input1").value);
var v = document.getElementById("input2").value;
var answer = document.getElementById("result");

if (!n) {
    alert("whatever is in input 1 is not a number ya fookin cheeky buggah");
}
if (n > v.length) {
    alert("number 1 bigger than word 2");
}
var res ="";
for(var i=1; i<=v.length; i++){
res = res +"\n"+ Array(i+1).join(v.charAt(i));
}
answer.innerHTML = res;
}
```

Whoever finds this answer to be useful or valid or wrong, please post ur comments or click the up/down arrow. Just to improve myself further.